# Testing Django model throws TypeError

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to test my REST API and am currently testing my models. I am very new at Django and testing in particular.

While testing my models I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got datetime.datetime(2022, ...)
```

I get this error for every model and view so far.

Why is this error occurring? How can I get my tests for this model to run?
Am I even testing properly?

This is one of my models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return self.name or ''

    @property
    def tags(self):
        tags = self.tagging.values('tag')
        return tags.values('tag_id', 'tag__name', 'tag__language')
```

And this is the corresponding test suite for this model:

```
class TagTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tag_name = "name of the tag"
        self.tag_language = "language of tag"
        self.tag = Tag.objects.create(name=self.tag_name, language=self.tag_language)

    def test_name_label(self):
        tag = Tag.objects.get(id=1)
        field_label = tag._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name()
        self.assertEqual(field_label, 'name')

    def test_tag_size(self):
        tag = Tag.objects.get(id=1)
        max_length = tag._meta.get_field('name').max_length
        self.assertEqual(max_length, 256)

    def test_str(self):
        """Test for string representation"""
        tag = Tag().objects.get(id=1)
        self.assertEqual(str(tag), tag.name)

    def test_model_can_create_tag(self):
        """Test the tagging model can create a tag instance"""
        old_count = Tag.objects.count()
        self.tag.save()
        new_count = Tag.objects.count()
        self.assertNotEqual(old_count, new_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a spot that you pass `datetime` object as an `id`.

But...

I've spotted some crucial mistakes:

```
tag = Tag().objects.get(id=1)
```

You are creating `Tag` object with `()`.

Another thing. If you create `self.tag = Tag.objects.create()` in `SetUp`, then the model is created for every test in `TestCase`. It means that you cannot `get` object with seeking `(id=1)` because the database is the same, but in `SetUp` it creates new object with new `id`. So, instead of:

```
def test_str(self):
    tag = Tag.objects.get(id=1)
    self.assertEqual(str(tag), tag.name)
```

You should simply use much safier approach:

```
def test_str(self):
    self.assertEqual(str(self.tag), self.tag.name)
```

Try to "hardcode" as little, as you can in tests.

Comment: I've corrected this but the error still persists. Thank you still!

Comment: If you give more Error track (it should precisely point to file and row) I might be able to help about that one too.